# Downloading Android App from PC to device

Tags: android, sdk

I successfully created Android apps under Win7/32 and downloaded them to a device (Galaxy GT-N7000). With another laptop under Win7/64, at first the device was not recognized. I got a driver from Samsung(UK) and this works, e.g. I can pass files between laptop and device etc. BUT: now, the device is no longer visible in Eclipse for the purpose of downloading apps (unlike the situation on the Win7/32 laptop).

Note: I checked in Eclipse>Window>Show View>Android>Devices: my emulators are listed there, but not the device. I could not find a command 'device management'.

Please advise; thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have 'Enable USB Debugging' turned on on your device in Settings|Developer Options

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Alex's answer , the option are as follows,

- Attach your .apk file in email and open that email in device, download and run.
- Attach your device with pc, select "Connect USB storage", copy .apk file in SD card's folder then dis-connect the cable and from device's file manager, install it.
- Last option is put your .apk file on some live ip's folder and open that live ip with full path in browser, it will directly download .apk file.